# Storing data using hibernate for inter related tables

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, orm

I have two tables (say table A and table B). Table B has foreign key from table A primary key. I generated my java entities using netbeans IDE and i now have something like:

For table A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORKFLOW_TRANSACTION")
public class WorkflowTransaction implements {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wtId")
private Collection<WorkflowTask> workflowTaskCollection;

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "APP_ID")
private BigDecimal appId;

.
.
.
```

For table B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORKFLOW_TASK")
public class WorkflowTask implements Serializable {

@JoinColumn(name = "WT_ID", referencedColumnName = "APP_ID")
@ManyToOne
private WorkflowTransaction wtId;

@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "TASK_ID")
private BigDecimal taskId;

@Column(name = "STEP_NUM")
private BigInteger stepNum;
.
.
.
```

Now my questions are:

1. What is the correct way to save data, should I create object for table B entity and set it in table A entity and then save table A?
2. I am generating entity beans using netbeans IDE feature. Are there any known disadvantages of it?, if yes, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bi-directional association, so you need to set`Table B` property in `Table A` entity class and also vice-versa. Since you have not declared cascading, you need to save the `Table A` entity first and then `Table B` entity.

Alternatively, if you save `Table B` and then `Table A` entity classes, the hibernate generates an extra SQL `update` command to maintain the relationship.

But if you want hibernate to save `Table B` entity when you save `Table A` entity then you need to add Cascade property:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wtId", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

I don't think you will have any disadvantages if you use Netbeans for generating the entity classes, it save you time in writing the entities. But if you want to learn then writing entities without Netbeans is good.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Also, what is the better way of doing it. Should I save table A and table B separately or together? Any performance difference between both ways?

Comment: If you don't use `cascade` as mentioned in my answer then you need to take care of saving both the entities. But save `Table A` first and then `Table B` using `session.save(Object)`. But if you use Cascade then Hibernate will take care of saving `Table B` entity when you save `Table A`. There is no performance issue here. What do you mean my saving separately vs together?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use two type of techniques XML mapping or Annotations
In both these techniques the common point is use
    cascade="save-update"
What happens is that you set an attribute in one table getter and it will automatically insert into the many relation when inserting into one relation table